# How to link to a specific part of a page HTML PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to link to a specific part in my php page. I have tried all the other answers on here but none of them have helped my special problem. This is how I am trying to go to the link

`<a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>#posts_tab">`

So when the user clicks the dropdown they see a list of things. One of those things being the word `Profile` and when the user clicks on their profile they go to their own personal profile. When they are there they have a list of items at the top that look like this:

[image]

So what I want to do is when they click the profile they are automatically on the Profile Posts tab. Like a default option. For some reason it's not working for me and I can't figure out why. Any help please ?

header.php:

```
<a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>#posts_tab">
</a>
```

profile.php:

```
<a style="color: #000;" id="posts_tab" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Posts');">
    <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">
        <center>Profile Posts</center>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want, you need to let your profile page know that you want to load that part of profile.php, you can do it different ways I have used php and GET as example, I've sent a parameter on the URL and received it on profile.php

header.php

```
<a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>?tab=posts_tab">
```

profile.php

```
<?php 
$tab = $_GET["tab"];
if ($tab == "posts_tab"){
?><script>openCity(event, 'Posts');</script><?php
}
?>
<a style="color: #000;" id="posts_tab" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity(event, 'Posts');">
    <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">
        <center>Profile Posts</center>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: check browser console for errors, you can also try this inside script tag <script>  window.onload = function() {openCity(event, 'Posts');}</script>

Comment: Console didn't show errors and that didn't help